# What to do when URL is available to Google, but has issues?

Tags: google-search-console, search-engine-indexing

I have a quite long page where I have a well explained content including images, videos, internal linking, external linking etc. The problem is when I want to index it, Google says "URL is available to Google, but has issues". And, when I "View Testd URL", it's just a plain HTML in the screenshot.

what can be causing this and what to do to solve it?
here's my `robots.txt` content:

```
User-Agent: Googlebot
Allow: .js
Allow: .css
User-Agent: *
Allow: /wp-content/uploads/
Disallow: /wp-content/plugins/
Disallow: /wp-admin/
Disallow: /readme.html
Disallow: /refer/

Sitemap: www.example.com/sitemap_index.xml
```

Comment: It could be that you are blocking style resources in your `robots.txt` file, which you will find at `https://example.com/robots.txt`

Comment: I putted my robots.txt content in the question body

Comment: What is your intent with that robots.txt?  Are you hoping that Google will follow the `User-Agent: *` rules and the `User-Agent: Googlebot` rules?

Comment: Yes. My intent is to see the page as it is in Google Search Console, the Screenshot I mean. Hoping to get it indexted with no issues. Hoping to rank as a result.

Answer (score 1):

There are several problems with your `robots.txt`:

- I would expect a wildcard in your `Allow: .js` rule: `Allow: *.js`. Without the wildcard, it wouldn't be allowing anything at all.
- There should be a blank line between `User-Agent` sections.
- Your sitemap is missing `https://`
- Your `Allow: /wp-content/uploads/` is superfluous. Nothing is disallowing the parent directory, so the uploads directory is already allowed.
- `User-Agent: Googlebot` does not add to the `User-Agent: *` rules, rather it replaces them.  If you want those same rules to apply to Googlebot, you need to duplicate them.

Here is a `robots.txt` file that should better match your intentions:

```
User-Agent: Googlebot
Allow: *.js
Allow: *.css
Disallow: /wp-content/plugins/
Disallow: /wp-admin/
Disallow: /readme.html
Disallow: /refer/

User-Agent: *
Disallow: /wp-content/plugins/
Disallow: /wp-admin/
Disallow: /readme.html
Disallow: /refer/

Sitemap: https://www.example.com/sitemap_index.xml
```

I would suggest allowing all bots to crawl your css and js. Googlebot isn't the only search engine that renders pages now.

```
User-Agent: *
Allow: *.js
Allow: *.css
Disallow: /wp-content/plugins/
Disallow: /wp-admin/
Disallow: /readme.html
Disallow: /refer/

Sitemap: https://www.example.com/sitemap_index.xml
```

You should use [Google's robots.txt tester tool](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/6062598?hl=en) to verify that Google can access the URLs you want it to crawl and that it can't access the URLs you don't want crawled.

After you make changes, you should also use [Google's URL Inspection Tool](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/9012289?hl=en) to run live tests against the URL.  The screenshots will tell you whether or not Googlebot is fetching the page as you intend or not.

Comment: despite allowing .js and .css in robots.txt, I am still seeing a plain html page in GSC. Why would that happen and what can i do to make it appear correctly?

Comment: Are your CSS files on a different domain, like a CDN? They would have a different robots.txt file. In GSC, view crawled page, then more info. It will tell you why resources failed to load.